# Forecasting panel data and time series

Tags: r, time-series, linear-regression, forecasting, panel-data

I have a panel data set of lets say 1000 observations, so

```
 i=1,2,...,1000
```

. The data set runs in daily basis for a month, so

```
t=1,2,...,31.
```

I want to estimate individual specific in R:

```
    y_i10=αi+βi∗yi9+γi∗yi8+...+δi∗yi1+ϵit
```

and then produce density forecasts for the next 21 days, that is produce density forecasts for

```
yi11,yi12 etc
```

My questions are:

1. Can I do this with plm package ? I am aware how to estimate with plm package but I do not know how to produce the forecasts.
2. Would it be easier (and correct) if I consider each observation as a separate time series, and use arima(9,0,0) for each one of them, and then get the density forecasts ? If so, how can I get the density forecasts ?
3. In (2.) , how can I include individual specific effects that are constant over time ?

Thanks a lot